# Parsing OpenURL data from wikipedia pages

Tags: python, parsing

I'm attempting to retrieve all of the citation data from any given wikipedia page. Looking at the wikipedia page a lot of the information that I require dare held in an [OpenURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenURL) object in a span in the reference section of the page.

The format of the span is as below:

```
<span 
    title="ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&amp;
    rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Ajournal&amp;
    rft.genre=unknown&amp;
    rft.jtitle=The+Tennessean&amp;
    rft.atitle=Belmont+University+awarded+final+2020+presidential+debate&amp;
    rft.date=2019-10-11&amp;
    rft.aulast=Tamburin&amp;
    rft.aufirst=Adam&amp;
    rft_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tennessean.com%2Fstory%2Fnews%2F2019%2F10%2F11%2Fbelmont-university-nashville-hosts-presidential-debate-2020%2F3941983002%2F&amp;
    rfr_id=info%3Asid%2Fen.wikipedia.org%3A2020+United+States+presidential+election" 

    class="Z3988">
</span>
```

So far I've been able to retrieve all the `span` using beautifulSoup and extracted the titles containing the data. However I'm stumped when it comes to parsing the text in the `title` field. I'm particularly interested in `rft.atitle`, `rft.date` and `rft_id`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


session = requests.Session()
targetWikiPage = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Beirut_explosion"

if "wikipedia" in targetWikiPage:
    html = session.post(targetWikiPage)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")

    html = session.post(targetWikiPage)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")


    wikiReferences = bsObj.find_all('span', {'class': 'Z3988'})
    wikiReferencesBS = BeautifulSoup(str(wikiReferences), "html.parser")

    for span in wikiReferencesBS.find_all():
        title = span['title']
        print(title)
```

#### Partial Solution

This solution provides a function which accepts the string and two flags. The start of the string we want to parse and the end of the first instance of the end flag.

The issue I now face is that of an `unboundLocalError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coinscraper.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(extractstring(title,flag1='rft.atitle=', flag2='&'))
  File "coinscraper.py", line 17, in extractstring
    return(string)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'string' referenced before assignment
```

Modification

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


session = requests.Session()
targetWikiPage = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Beirut_explosion"


def extractstring(line,flag1, flag2):
    if flag1 in line: # $ is the flag
        dex1=line.index(flag1)
        subline=line[dex1+len(flag1):-1] #leave out flag (+1) to end of line
        dex2=subline.index(flag2)
        string=subline[0:dex2].strip() #does not include last flag, strip whitespace
        string = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(string)

    return(string)

if "wikipedia" in targetWikiPage:
    html = session.post(targetWikiPage)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")

    html = session.post(targetWikiPage)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")


    wikiReferences = bsObj.find_all('span', {'class': 'Z3988'})
    wikiReferencesBS = BeautifulSoup(str(wikiReferences), "html.parser")

    for span in wikiReferencesBS.find_all():
        title = span['title']

        print(extractstring(title,flag1='rft.atitle=', flag2='&'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it this way:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

targetWikiPage = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Beirut_explosion"

response = requests.get(targetWikiPage).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser").find_all('span', {'class': 'Z3988'})


def get_rfts():
    for i in soup:
        for rft in i['title'].split("&"):
            yield rft


keep = ["rft.atitle", "rft.date", "rft_id"]
for rft in get_rfts():
    rft_key, rft_value = rft.split("=")
    if rft_key in keep:
        print(unquote(rft_value).replace("+", " "))
```

Output:

```
'Endemic corruption' caused Beirut blast, says Diab: Live updates
https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/08/beirut-police-fire-tear-gas-protesters-regroup-live-updates-200810010528285.html
Lebanon's government 'to resign over blast'
2020-08-10
https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-53720383
Beirut Explosion Generates Seismic Waves Equivalent Of A Magnitude 3.3 Earthquake
https://www.forbes.com/sites/davidbressan/2020/08/06/beirut-port-explosion-triggers-magnitude-3-earthquake/
Many injured as large blast rocks Beirut
2020-08-04
https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-53656220
Beirut explosion 'one of the largest non-nuclear blasts in history'
2020-08-05
https://www.standard.co.uk/news/world/beirut-explosion-one-of-largest-blasts-history-a4517646.html
Second day of protests as anger over Beirut explosion grows: Live
https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/08/hundreds-protesters-injured-anger-simmers-beirut-live-200808234355971.html
Clashes Erupt in Beirut at Blast Protest as Lebanon's Anger Boils Over
...
```